# Qubes/Xen OS: access file manager for dom0

Tags: files, terminal, kde, xen, qubes

I hope somebody more experienced with Qubes specific terminal commands can help.

> If the KDE manager is installed, how does one open via terminal input the file manager for 'dom0'? To browse 'Home' in the GUI.

I do not have a `dom0: Files` in the GUI, like I do for all other Virtual Machines. This opens the `Home` file structure in the GUI for all the other VMs.

Now `dom0` does have a `Home`. When I had a fuller installation (kde + xfce, select at login) I had an option, in Application Launcher Menu, in System Tools, the name of the file manager was in the system tools menu, which automatically opened `Home` of `dom0`.

What do I enter into the `dom0` terminal to open `Home` in whatever file manager is installed. (No, I have no idea what it was called. I did not remember from the other installation. I may or may not be the file manager KDE used, I don't know.) >Or how would I get the file manager for dom0 icon to display in the Application Launcher Menu?

MY FAILED ATTEMPTS SO FAR: `Konqueror` or `Dolphin` gives `command not found` in dom0 `Konsole`. `qvm-run dom0 /home` gives me info about /home.

xdg-open /home opens a copy of the Application Launcher Menu, which is still missing the Files or [file manager name] option.
If I run in the command area: `qubes-vm-setting dom0 applications`, which `qubes-vm-setting [vmname] applications` opens up the shortcuts to programs tool, I get a crash and error log: no such place in /usr.
So dom0 does not have a setting tool, rather it is the system setting tool.
However it does have a `/home` directory because it is another VM. Just how to open it in file manager...

`Add/remove App shortcuts` is grayed out for dom0 in Qubes VM Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing `thunar /home` on a terminal in `dom0` opens the Thunar file manager in my Qubes installation that uses the current default xfce environment.  I'm not familiar with the current Qubes KDE environment, but Unix/Linux is case sensive.  Instead of `Konqueror` or `Dolphin`, have you tried `konqueror` or `dolphin`?

It's best to access the Home directories in the VMs instead in order to preserve the compartmentalization of your installation.

NB: A shortcut for the GUI of the Thunar File Manager is available also in the xfce environment at Menu/System Tools/Thunar File Manager.  I'm not an expert, but I prefer to avoid using any Qt or xfce interfaces especially in dom0 or the template VMs.  It might be best to install Midnight Commander (`sudo dnf install mc`), which provides a GUI file manager within a terminal.